# How to Iterate over a String Array inside .map()

Tags: java, java-8

So i have these lines in a method -

```
private List<String> buildLwaScopePermissionsList(final List<Permission> permissions) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(permissions).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
               .stream()
               .map(Permission::getName)
               .map(Permission.Name::getValues)
               .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf));
   }
```

where Permission is a class and Name is a static inner class inside Permission Class, and getName() is a non-static method inside Permission class and  getValues() is a static method inside Name class. The problem is getValues method returns a String Array. I am not able to pick up 1 by 1 item form the returned values and concatinate with Name and store it in the list.

```
 public static String[] getValues() {
            return values.clone();
        }
```

Comment: Simply add another mapping, like `.map(vals -> vals[0])`, just before `collect`.

Comment: Can you give an example input of `Name` , `values` and an `output` you want.

Comment: *I am not able to pick up 1 item form the returned values and concatinate with Name* .. which one value out of the array and where is the concatenation in the current code in place?

Comment: sample input is 
Name = "1"
Value = "2"
The list will store 1st element as "12", 
like that for 1 name there will be different values. 
like List = {12,13,14,15}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten multiple values into one stream.

If you have a single permission, you can get a Stream of the concatenated Names by doing `Arrays.stream(Permission.Name.getValues()).map(val -> permission.getName() + val)`. By using `flatMap`, you can put all these values into the original Stream:

```
private List<String> buildLwaScopePermissionsList(final List<Permission> permissions) {
   return Optional.ofNullable(permissions).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
           .stream()
           .flatMap(permission -> Arrays.stream(Permission.Name.getValues()).map(val -> permission.getName() + val))
           .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), ImmutableList::copyOf));
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what "permission" stands for 
```
val -> permission.getName() + val
```

getName() is a non-static method .
I tried creating an object of Permission class and tried accessing the way u specifed but throwing error. and Directly by classname.method() i cannot access as it is not a static method.

Comment: @soumitbose Oh, I forgot the lambda paremeter, I've corrected that omission

Comment: @Holger No. Please read the clarifying comments under the OP. What you are suggesting is furthermore rather senseless, since `Permission.Name` is static as well as `Permission.Name.getValues()`, and thus you'll end up with a stream of all values n times, where n is the number of entries in the list of given permissions. OP has clearly stated they want to concatenate those static names which are the same for every permission with the instance-level `Permission::getName` method, resulting in unique strings for each permission. The concatenation part is already in the OP, but clarified later.

Comment: ur solution worked fine. but what to do in case i want to pick up only the first value from the returned string array of getValues() ?

Comment: @soumitbose You can access the fist element of an array with `array[0]`. Since you do not have multiple values anymore, you don't need `flatMap` anymore, so the line in question becomes `.flatMap(permission -> permission.getName() + Permission.Name.getValues()[0]))`. If you have further follow-up question that aren't part of your original question, please ask a new question, but this stuff is very basic.